# Auditing collection of @Embeddables with overridden equals/hashCode in JPA2/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, equals, hashcode, hibernate-envers

I have a setting of JPA2/Hibernate. Furthermore, the entities are audited by Hibernate Envers. I have the following class to signify postal codes with only one field, namely `value`.

It all works fine when saving only one instance of any postal code to the `Set<PostalCode>`. However, when I try to add another postal code, the auditing fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [PostalCodesAudit#{PostOffice_id=5, revision_id=DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 16, revisionDate = Aug 19, 2013 8:50:05 AM), revisionType=ADD}]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1359)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:80)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:513)
... 58 more
```

The curious thing here is that it works fine, when I remove the implementations of `equals` and `hashCode` from the `PostalCode` class, the mechanism works fine. Also, if I change the collection to `Set<String>`, similar mapping works perfectly.

I am not absolutely required to implement `equals` and `hashCode` in the `PostalCode` class, but I'm not overly keen on dropping the support, either.

What is the correct way to map this kind of situation?

#### Entities

```
@Embeddable
public class PostalCode {
    @Column(name = "postalCode", length = 5)
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9}{5}")
    private String value;

    // Getter and setter for value

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof PostalCode)) {
            return false;
        }
        PostalCode that = (PostalCode) o;
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(this.value, that.value).isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder().append(this.value).toHashCode();
    }
}
```

In another class I try to use this as an `@ElementCollection`:

```
@Valid
@ElementCollection(targetClass = PostalCode.class)
@CollectionTable(name="PostalCodes", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "postOffice_id"))
private Set<PostalCode> postalCodes = new HashSet<PostalCode>();
```

#### Edit 1

Further investigation reveals that if the type of the collection is `Collection<PostalCode>` or `List<PostalCode>`, the auditing will fail even without the `equals/hashCode` implementations:

```
// No difference in the following
private Collection<PostalCode> postalCodes = new HashSet<PostalCode>();
private Collection<PostalCode> postalCodes = new ArrayList<PostalCode>();
```

re
And as a further note, the `EntityExistsException` thrown does not contain the value of the postal code: only the foreign key, revision_id, and revisionType are included.

```
// Excerpt from the exception
PostalCodesAudit#{
    PostOffice_id=5,
    revision_id=DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 16, revisionDate = Aug 19, 2013 11:52:14 AM),
    revisionType=ADD
}
```

Furthermore, after changing the field to `List<PostalCode>` and annotating it with `@OrderColumn` the audit mechanism works without exception regardless of whether `equals/hashCode` is implemented or not. It still breaks without the order column

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = PostalCode.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "PostOfficePostalCodes", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "postOffice_id"))
@OrderColumn(name = "listOrder")
private List<PostalCode> postalCodes = new ArrayList<PostalCode>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving it by converting the field to a `List<PostalCode>` even though this is not the optimal solution since the list allows duplicate entries. The final mapping is as follows:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "postOffice_id"))
@Column(name = "postalCode", unique = true)
@OrderColumn(name = "listOrder")
private List<PostalCode> deliveredPostalCodes = new ArrayList<PostalCode>();
```